# how you can get the name of a specific item from a List

Tags: c#, list

From the following example asked a question.

```
List<Report> lista = new List<Report>();
lista.add (new Report {. Name = "Report1"});
lista.add (new Report {. Name = "report2"});
lista.add (new Report {. Name = "report3"});
lista.add (new Report {. Name = "report4"});
```

how you can get the name of the report number 3?

thank you very much.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: If I understand the question....(which I may not) - if you add an Id property to the Report object you could use Linq to order them by Id and select a single report based on it's Id. The code above doesn't look like valid C# though so I hope you realise this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "report number 3" you mean the third report, you can do this:

```
lista[2].Name
```

If by "report number 3" you mean that there is an additional property on `Report` (e.g. `Id`), then you can do this:

```
lista.First(x => x.Id == 3).Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lista[2].Name
```

Note lists are indexed from 0, so the first element would be `lista[0]`.

Also, note that in `C#` we don't use leading `.` in inline object initializers, so it should be

```
List<Report> lista = new List<Report>();
lista.add (new Report {Name = "Report1"});
lista.add (new Report {Name = "report2"});
lista.add (new Report {Name = "report3"});
lista.add (new Report {Name = "report4"});
```

Also, you may want to initialize the list as well:

```
List<Report> lista = new List<Report>(){
    new Report {Name = "Report1"},
    new Report {Name = "Report2"},
    new Report {Name = "Report3"},
    new Report {Name = "Report4"}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd item in the list can be accessed through:

```
string name = lista[2].Name;
```